# ERROR: thread attach failed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am getting this following error during run time.

```
ERROR: thread attach failed
```

My project contains two classes in src as fallowing:

1. Activity class
2. video_thread class

I've created an object for this video_thread class in Activity class, made it Daemon and started it like this:

```
video_thread v=new video_thread();
video_thraed.setDaemon(true);
video_thread.start();
```

During execution i am finding this error in the logcat.

Comment: Maybe you should paste some logcat in here.  The error message is emitted by the Android runtime during startup, and is usually seen when you run a command like "adb shell am".  I doubt it's being emitted by your application, but to know for sure you'd want to check the process ID in the logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is cause because you application is shutting down whilst the thread is trying to be created. See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/addd2a507ea8b166

You should try figure out why your application is exiting whilst the thread is being created.

Comment: thank you.. the error has no significance.. 
it can be ignored.. 

my project is working even when this error is popping.. 
actually there is an error in my logic that's all.. 
Thank you.. Now its cleared..

Comment: Glad to hear it! So, if you are happy with my response I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct. Thanks!